# How to catch images with blank dimensions?

Tags: plugin-development, images, regex

I've created a [WordPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/specify-image-dimensions/) that inserts `width` and `height` attributes to all images, for example:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50">
- to -
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="100" height="50">
```

Yet, when there are images that have blank dimensions (for both `width` and `height`), my code doesn't doesn't catch it, for example:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="" height="">
```

However, when there is only one blank dimension, my plugin does catch it. The following two examples will work:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" width="">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" height="">
```

[Here's the source code](https://github.com/factmaven/specify-image-dimensions/blob/master/specify-image-dimensions.php). On line 43 ([#](https://github.com/factmaven/specify-image-dimensions/blob/master/specify-image-dimensions.php#L43)), this is the logic I'm using to determine if an image is missing a `width`/`height`:

```
if ( ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ) {
```

I've tried the following updated logic, but it doesn't work:

```
if ( # Images with no width/height
    ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ||
    # Images with blank width/height
    ( in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[1] ) ) || ( in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[1] ) )
) {
```

Am I in the right area? What am I doing wrong in my logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, the first thing I would do after matching the attributes is to create an associative array of:

```
array( 'attribute_name' => 'attribute_value' )
```

It will make it easier to get the attribute directly than having to search the array and I think overall it will make the code more direct. Since we know that index 0 is our attribute names and index 1 is our attribute values, we can use [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to create the format listed above:

```
$attributes = array_combine( $img[1], $img[2] );
```

Finally, we can strip out any empty values from the array by finding the difference and then run the conditional.

```
$attributes = array_diff( $attributes, array( '""' ) );
```

---

Of course the above you would have to refactor your code to account for the new associative array `$attributes['src']` and so forth. The problem with your original solution was you were searching for the value in the 1 index where you should have looked in the 2 index( which contains the values ):

```
if ( # Images with no width/height
    ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) || ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ||
    # Images with blank width/height
    ( in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) ) || ( in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) )
) {
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now that I got it working. I am planning to simply the code as you recommended.